# javascript if else click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add an if else statement to the below

```
$('#togglediv4').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $('#link4').attr('src','images/contact_link_clicked.png');
});
```

I want the image to change back to the original one if there is no click event otherwise all links once clicked will remain stuck on the new image.

Therefore if image is not clicked I want to show the original image.

```
$('#link4').attr('src','images/contact_link_original.png');
```

Comment: I lost you half way there...so whatis it exactly that u want???

Comment: is this jquery? if so, tag it as such

Comment: u want to add if else..then add it why ask???

Comment: I tried to add if else but cannot get the correct format right

Comment: Do all your images have a common class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just set the `src` attribute of the original `<img>` tag to: mages/contact_link_original.png

Then add the click event as above.

By default when your div hasnt been clicked it will contain the original image.

EDIT: based on your comment I would do the following:

- Add a class to all the images
- When any image is clicked change the src attr back to the original on ALL images with that class. (You can use `$('.imgClass')`)
- Then update the image that was clicked with the new image.

Comment: but once clicked I do want the image to turn back to the original as soon as another image is clicked

Comment: this $('.imgclass').attr('src','images/newhome_link.png'); specifies all images within the class, can I specify each image src separately within the class ?

Comment: for each click I turned back the other images links to their original images. I specified the src for each image in all functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `attr` callback function and ternary operator.

```
$('#togglediv4').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#link4').attr('src',function(i, src){
          return src === 'images/contact_link_original.png'
          ? 'images/contact_link_clicked.png'
          : 'images/contact_link_original.png'
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question correctly, but it looks to me like you need to use the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events instead of `click`:

```
$('#togglediv4').mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#link4').attr('src','images/contact_link_clicked.png');
}).mouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#link4').attr('src','images/contact_link_original.png');
});
```

Comment: unfortunately this works only if the mouse is left clicked down, else it will turn back to original. I want to keep the image changed until another image is clicked

Comment: @user1347219 Ah, I wasn't understanding your question correctly then. In that case I'd look at [undefined's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14067910/618347).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$('#togglediv4').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#link4').attr('src') == 'images/contact_link_original.png') {
        $('#link4').attr('src','images/contact_link_clicked.png');
    }       
});
```